# Issues in installation of dev version of ggmap library in R

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap, devtools

I am using RStudio to with R 3.5.2 installed in my Windows 7 machine.
I am trying to use ggmap to load google map based on certain parameters but this fails because the authentication key is not provided and a 403 error as below occurs

> Error in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
>    cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?>center=29.763284,-95.363271&zoom=4&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&sensor=>false'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
>    cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?>center=29.763284,-95.363271&zoom=4&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&sensor=>false': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

A lot of posts suggests installing a dev version of ggmap after which you can use the maps API key by  using

```
// save api key
register_google(key = "YOUR_API_KEY")
```

Thus I am trying to install the dev version using,

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
```

but on trying to install the dev version of ggmap the error is as below

```
 devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

any suggestions/help would be nice,
Thanks

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no I am not behind a proxy

Comment: Have you tried on of the [solutions proposed here](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/issues/272)?